# Fetching files from pythonless remote hosts

Tags: ansible

I know that I can manage remote hosts that don't have python installed (or it's too old python) using 'raw' and 'script' modules. It's possible to upload some file and execute it as script, or run some arbitrary command. But how can I fetch some file from remote host? Something like 'fetch' module which requires python?

Comment: You install python with `raw` then you use the `fetch` module. Else you can also not use ansible at all and transfer the file with `scp` (since you should have an ssh access at this point).

Comment: I'm not permitted to install anything on remote system.

Comment: "It's possible to upload some file and execute it as script, or run some arbitrary command." How is that done (which commands, etc)? What OS name/version are the remote hosts using? Can you ssh into them?

Comment: Without (a decent) python on the target, [you can only use `raw` and `script` modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements) (basically to install prereqs to run ansible normally afterwards). If you cannot install anything and can only use those 2 modules, there is absolutely no added value to using ansible over plain ssh. => use ssh and scp.

Comment: I have only 2 very old RHEL 5.0 hosts that I can't upgrade. Rest of my hosts are decent.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `scp` on the Ansible host to fetch files.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch a file
      local_action: ansible.builtin.command scp {{ inventory_hostname }}:/path/to/file /tmp/.
```

See [delegating tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) in the documentation.

Comment: This hack works perfectly with plain ansible, but it doesn't work if I use Ansible AWX (Tower). I don't know how to authenticate scp. I can define some credentials within AWX, but how can I pass them to the scp command run as local_action?

Comment: @Motueka Do not use credentials. Use [public key authentication](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-ssh-public-key-authentication/).

Comment: In the AWX I can also add ssh key as a 'credential' and it can be used to access remote system, however 'ansible.builtin.command scp' method requires public key from awx-task container. This is not so conveniant but works.